# Как узнать под каким номером идет элемент?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть список:

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li class='play'>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

В jquery есть функция .eq() которая возвращает элемент идущий под заданным номером.
Как узнать под каким номером идет элемент с class='play' ?

Comment: перебором `$('ul').children().each()` ?

Comment: Выполняет заданную функцию для каждого из выбранных элементов в отдельности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  if ( $(this).attr('class')=='play' ) console.log( 'Индекс: ' + index + ", текст внутри: " + $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: я думал проще сначала селект сделать а потом сравнивать ===

Comment: ???

 ... .attr('class')=='play'

.hasClass('class') // не?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, мы отвечаем на вопрос "Как узнать под каким номером идет элемент с class='play'?", а не на "... содержит класс play".

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, разве не очевидно, что использование attr здесь неуместно?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, нет, не очевидно. Читайте внимательно, по буквам: "элемент с class='play'".

Comment: Все с вами ясно, понять что именно донес ТС вы не смогли (либо делаете вид что не смогли). Anyway, даже если так, то использование attr все-равно не уместно, prop('className').

Comment: И в чем разница между attr() и prop() при обращению к свойству class?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman - грубо говоря, prop это

    return somjqueryobject[0][prop];

а attr это

    return somjqueryobject[0].getAttribute(prop);

Соответственно attr целесообразно использовать для нестандартных аттрибутов:

    <img ololo="100500">


    $('img').attr('ololo');

more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul').find('li.play').index();
```